# CRM 2013 - Plugin to retrieve username

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2013

I have an AutoNumber plug-in that invokes when the user presses save, but I've received a requirement to append the initials of the person creating the record to the end of the ticket.

For example: 0001-0327-RBS

I have been able to get the GUID of the user creating the record, but I have no idea how to get the literal value outside of SQL. I haven't been able to figure out how I can get the user name of the active user creating the record. Is this possible from within a plug-in?

any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get IOrganizationService from IServiceProvider

```
var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
var serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
var service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
```

now you can simply retrieve the SystemUser using the service:

```
var systemUser = service.Retrieve("systemuser", context.UserId, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet(true));
```

in ColumnSet you can specify the columns which you want to retrieve (so for example "firstname", "lastname", "fullname" etc.).

Now you can simply do

```
systemUser["fullname"]
```

to get the name. Or if you are using early binds:

```
systemUser.ToEntity<SystemUser>().FullName
```

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. Initially implementation did not work, but once I changed the location (local vs global var) it retrieved the information I needed. Thank you very much!